# Sending data through interface-null reference. Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Fragment

```
    public class page2_saved_notes extends Fragment {
        public static final String SAVE = "MyPrefsArrays";
        private String mTitleArray = "titlesArray";
        private String mNotesArray = "notesArray";

        ArrayList<String> arrayListTitle = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> arrayListNotes = new ArrayList<>();
        communicateCheckboxes cc;
        String json;
        Gson gson;
        Type type;
        String jsonNotes;
        Type typeNotes;
        SharedPreferences settings;

    //update
        private Listener listener;
        public interface Listener {
            void sendData(String title, String Notes);
        }


        public page2_saved_notes() {
        }

        public static page2_saved_notes newInstance() {
            page2_saved_notes fragment = new page2_saved_notes();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2_saved_notes, container, false);

            //interface / preferences / gson initialize
   //update
            listener = (Listener) getActivity();
            settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SAVE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            gson = new Gson();

            //retrieve title from memory
            json = settings.getString(mTitleArray, null);
            type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {
            }.getType();
            arrayListTitle = gson.fromJson(json, type);

            //retrieve notes from memory
            jsonNotes = settings.getString(mNotesArray, null);
            typeNotes = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {
            }.getType();
            arrayListNotes = gson.fromJson(jsonNotes, typeNotes);


      //update
                if(listener!= null)
                listener.sendData("check","check");

            return rootView;
        }
```

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, page1_user_notes.communicate,page2_saved_notes.communicateCheckboxes{

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    //checkbox array list
    public ArrayList<CheckBox> checkBoxArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    //user titleText Array List
    public ArrayList<String> titleTextArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    //user notesArrayList
    public ArrayList<String> notesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, ''yy");
    String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
   // PopupMenu popup
    LinearLayout ll;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp;
    PopupMenu popup;
    CheckBox checkbox;
    private int checkboxPopupCheck;

    String checkTitle;
    String checkNotes;

    //shared preferences
    public static final String SAVE = "MyPrefsArrays";
    private String mTitleArray = "titlesArray";
    private String mNotesArray = "notesArray";

    //might not need this.Just recreate the checkboxes in onCreate
    //private String mCheckBoxArray = "checkBoxArray";



    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // recovering the instance state
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        /***-----------Added after----------*/
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //initialize shared preferences
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(SAVE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        //add titles array to saved preferences
        String jsonTitle = gson.toJson(titleTextArrayList);
        editor.putString(mTitleArray,jsonTitle);

        //may not need this
        //add notes array to saved preferences
        String jsonNotes = gson.toJson(notesArrayList);
        editor.putString(mNotesArray,jsonNotes);

        //add checkbox array to saved preferences

        editor.commit();

    }



    //might not need this
/*    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

    }*/

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendData(String userText, String userNotes) {
        //----Start of checkbox layout
        ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
        lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        checkbox = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
        checkbox.setTextSize(20);
        checkbox.setText(userText + "  \n" + date);
        checkbox.setLayoutParams(lp);
        checkbox.setClickable(false);
        checkbox.setButtonDrawable(null);
        //----End of checkbox layout

        //save text components to the file
        writeToFile(userText,userNotes);

        //Add text components to the arrays
        titleTextArrayList.add(userText);
        notesArrayList.add(userNotes);

        //add the checkbox to the array
        //so that we can delete it or whatever later
        checkBoxArrayList.add(checkbox);

        //add checkbox to the Linear layout
        ll.addView(checkbox);

        //-----Delete the Checkbox,Title,and Notes in the arrays if it already exists----Data is saved to previous version----//
        //check the data being sent through
        //erases the text from title text array if it is equal to the same title name.
        //this avoids same data from being saved
        datacheck(userText);

        //set touch listener for the checkboxes.
        for(int i = 0; i < checkBoxArrayList.size(); i++){

            checkBoxArrayList.get(i).setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                        view.postDelayed(runnable, 0);

                        for(int i = 0; i < checkBoxArrayList.size();i++) {
                            checkBoxArrayList.get(i).setId(i);

                        }
                        checkboxPopupCheck = view.getId();
                        checkTitle = titleTextArrayList.get(checkboxPopupCheck) +".txt";
                        checkNotes = titleTextArrayList.get(checkboxPopupCheck)+"_Notes.txt";
                         //Log.i("I Value = ",Integer.toString(checkboxPopupCheck));
                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, changeToast(checkBoxArrayList.get(view.getId()).getText()) + "is selected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //set check var to the checkbox that's pressed down.
                        //test for which item is selected
                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,Integer.toString(checkboxPopupCheck)+ "is selected.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    return false;
                }


            });
            }
        }
```

Working on passing the saved data from my `onPause()` in `MainActivity` through an interface inside of my fragment. The reason I do this is because I need to have the fragment initialized before I can create the checkboxes through `sendData` in `Main Activity` after the user closes and restarts the program.

Log cat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference

at com.MyApp.notes.MainActivity.sendData(MainActivity.java:169)
at com.MyApp.notes.page2_saved_notes.onCreateView(page2_saved_notes.java:89)
```

It seems as though the view is not initialized yet inside of the fragment before I send the data.

How can I call `sendData` from my fragment with my saved data to recreate my checkboxes?

Answer:
Thanks for helping Moshe Edri. Here is where I went wrong...

I needed to initialize the layout inside of the fragment and just create a new method in main(Basically copy and paste, except add LinearLayout parameter/new name for the method) to pass the data + the layout.

Fragment

1)I changed the interface:

```
public interface communicateCheckboxes {
        void sendData2(String title, String Notes, LinearLayout layout);
    }
```

2) added the layout variable to fragment and initialized in onCreate();

```
LinearLayout ll;//initalize

ll = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.myLayout);//onCreate()
```

3)Send data through onCreate() in fragment.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < arrayListNotes.size(); i++) {
            Log.i("CHECKING",arrayListTitle.get(i));
           if(cc!= null) {
            cc.sendData2(arrayListTitle.get(i), arrayListNotes.get(i),ll);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

when you  declare an interface to talk to a fragment you need to do this like that:

```
 public interface Listener {
        void sendData(String title, String Notes);
    }
```

you don't get to pick the name , it's like extending any object

then you need to implement your listener as you did but ...

create variable like that :

```
private Listener listener;`
```

in your fragment

```
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof Activity) {
        listener = (Listener) context;
    }
}
```

then you can call your function

```
  if(listener != null){
listener.sendData("title" , "notes");
}
```

Comment: What kind of listener?

Comment: Because I inflate the view in the fragment before I call the method. So I'm not sure why its saying it cant call the method on the view...

Comment: `//send data to main activity
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayListNotes.size()-1; i++) {
            cc.sendData(arrayListTitle.get(i), arrayListNotes.get(i));
        }`  added a minus 1 to size of array so it doesn't go out of bounds. It compiles and runs, but doesn't retain data and remake the checkboxes.

Comment: i get this log cat error `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.Myapp.notes.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.Myapp.notes.page2_saved_notes$Listener`...duh i didnt implement..1 sec

Comment: show me how and where you try to cast it, update your code in the quetion

Comment: I figured it out. Ill post the code soon. I will give you +1 for helping me.